# Alias that runs a command using sudo

Tags: sudo, alias

Im always running a particular app as root because it requires more privileges.
I usually just sudo it.
I want to make an alias that is something similar to:
`alias myCmd='sudo nohup /path/to/binary > /dev/null 2>&1 &'`

The problem arises when sudo prompts for password and then nothing will happen actually.
How can it be done?

Comment: Why are you sending it to the background using `&` when you're already using `nohup`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a shell script instead of an alias.

in ~/.bashrc:

```
export PATH="$PATH":~/bin
```

your script in ~/bin/runthat:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo nohup /path/to/binary > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

Then to run it, just do it like:

```
$ runthat
```

Or if you skipped the PATH step, then run it like:

```
$ ~/bin/runthat
```

If this is a system-wide (all users) script instead of just you, then put it in /usr/local/bin instead.

Or also you could use a function. eg. in ~/.bashrc:

```
runthat() {
    sudo nohup /path/to/binary > /dev/null 2>&1 &
}
```

Also just FYI and not a direct answer to the question, another alternative is to put it in the sudoers file:

```
sudo visudo
    (your editor pops up here)
    username ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/binary
```

And now it won't ask for a password at all. (which means lower security... maybe some security exploit will now let malware run this app too... so make sure you accept that small risk)

Comment: I was hoping to just an alias, without all the boilerplate, but I can work with that. Thanks

Comment: I was beating myself over the head trying to get these aliases to work. I knew I could create bash scripts but thought it would be better to use aliases. My perfectionist nature wouldn't let me give it up. Anyone reading this..just use scripts. Don't be like me lol

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the bottom of your ~/.bashrc

```
alias sudo="sudo " # space after sudo
```